# How to resolve an error at reactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "/src/App.jsx";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.jsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "/src/Home.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/webapp-3tw58

Getting an error, not understanding how to resolve it

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `App`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done some mistake over there, regarding `import` and all that.

First thing is you can't import with file extension.

<s>import App from "/src/App.jsx";</s>

instead

`import App from "/src/App";`

and same for `App.jsx` file as well.

`import Home from "/src/Home";`

**OR**

I'll suggest to use the relative import,

`import App from "./App";`

Maybe this is causing the actual issue.

**Updated:**

By looking into your codesandbox, you're using the `react-router-dom@v6` and there is a different way of using the `Route`. Please read it from [here.](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Pradip Dhakal, this is likely an issue caused by react-router-dom version mismatch. Updating route definition as per new [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) seems to solve the issue:

App.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
  return <div>Home</div>;
}

export default Home;
```